# При среднем весе (в) 850 грамм

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Нужен ли предлог "в" в этом предложении?
**При среднем весе (в) 850 грамм.**

Answer (score 2):

Классический вариант: **при среднем весе в 850 грамм.**

Более употребительный вариант: **при среднем весе  850 грамм**.

Первый  вариант указан в Грамматике-80 и в словарях:

ВЕС, 1. Физ. Сила тяжести. 2. Разг. и спец. Количество, масса кого-, чего-л., определяемая взвешиванием. В. товара, багажа. Борец лёгкого, тяжёлого веса. **Контейнер весом в сто килограммов**.

В то же время Розенталь **в подобных числовых сочетаниях** допускает обе формы, причем указывает, что беспредложная конструкция используется  чаще (можно предположить, что именно она является разговорным вариантом).

**ДЛИНА — длиной, длиной в.**

Дорога длиной 20 километров; Мост длиной в 2 километра. **Чаще употребляется беспредложная конструкция:** Пляж длиной 10 километров. При отсутствии числительного (числа) употребляется предложная конструкция: Улица длиной в километр.

**Пояснение**

Вариант с предлогом В (управление В.п.)  — это **точное грамматическое сочетание** со значением меры или количества: дом в три этажа, записка в два слова, шишка в кулак, зеркало во всю стену.

Но если в качестве меры используется **числовой оборот с указанной единицей измерения**, то значение сочетания и так ясно, поэтому предлог В для простоты **опускается**.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

При среднем весе (каком весе?) 850 грамм.

Похожие примеры:

При росте 170 см. 

При высоте 5 метров.

Но:

При увеличении (в сколько?) в 100 раз.

Чтобы использовать "в", нужно поменять склонение:

Средним весом в 850 грамм.